# Radiobutton value is not returning in Pycharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, python-idle, radiobuttonlist

I have a code that returns the value of a radio button, but the value is not returning in pycharm. I have tried both tkinter and pysimplegui packages. The code is returning the value when using IDLE is there any solution to this problem?. My code is given below.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
myLabel = Label(root, text="Select type of Report(Monthly/Cummulative").pack()
r = IntVar()
print(r.get())
x = r.get()
def clicked(value):
    myLabel = Label(root, text=value)
    myLabel.pack()
    x=value
    print("x inside:", x)
    return x;  # Return tuple, we could also
    # write (str, x)

Radiobutton(root, text="Monthly Report", variable=r, value=1, command= lambda: clicked(1)).pack()
print("x outside:", x)
Radiobutton(root, text="Cummulative Report", variable=r, value=2, command= lambda: clicked(2)).pack()
myLabel = Label(root, text=r.get())
myLabel.pack()
x = clicked(x)  # Assign returned tuple
print("Value from function :",x )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How the value is not returning in pycharm ?

Comment: Your code is calling `r.get()` and `clicked(x)` about a millisecond after creating the widgets. The user won't have had a chance to see the widgets, much less type into them.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with PyCharm. And the value is returning. You should try to rebuild it and tested it.
[image]